# Choose which browser Webpack opens?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I installed Vue.js using the CLI as found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html):

```
# install vue-cli
$ npm install --global vue-cli
# create a new project using the "webpack" template
$ vue init webpack my-project
# install dependencies and go!
$ cd my-project
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

When I run it opens Safari, my default browser. I would like to specify Chrome (used only for development) without changing the OS default browser.

The webpack.dev.conf.js is as follows:

```
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')

// add hot-reload related code to entry chunks
Object.keys(baseWebpackConfig.entry).forEach(function (name) {
  baseWebpackConfig.entry[name] = ['./build/dev-client'].concat(baseWebpackConfig.entry[name])
})

module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': config.dev.env
    }),
    // https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    new FriendlyErrorsPlugin()
  ]
})
```

Anybody know how to specify Chrome in this configuration?

Answer (score 13):

There is already a issue assigned for it on github but it's still under development.

[Issue Link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/825)

**Update**

The issue finally got merged. Now you can specify the browser using CLI or webpack.dev.conf.

1. Using CLI  `"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open chrome"`
2. Using  webpack.config.js:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     //...
     devServer: {
       open: 'Google Chrome'
     }
   };
   ```

   [Documentation Link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-open)

Comment: So that `PR` finally got merged and now allows for the `--open` cmd arg. For example `--open firefox`. Or in the config: `open: "Google Chrome"`.

Comment: My webpack execution is buried several layers deep beneath yarn commands in a lerna monorepo that run multiple servers at once, so CLI params aren't feasible.

Is there a way to specify this via env vars, so that I don't have to commit to source control the browser I want to test with today? 

Comment: If 'Google Chrome' does not work on Windows 10, try 'chrome'. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For DevServer **v4.0.0+**

> webpack.config.json

```
{
  // ...
  devServer:
  {
    open:
    {
      app:
      {
        name: 'firefox'
      }
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

> CLI

```
npx webpack serve --open-app-name 'firefox'
```

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropen

Answer (score 0):

For vue-cli 5.04,
the only version that seems to work currently is in vue.config.js

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
    devServer: {
        open: {
            app: {
                name: 'opera',
            }
        }
    },
});
```

however

```
vue-cli-service serve --open-app-name 'opera'
```

does not work.